# How can I make two files interact (new)

Tags: java, function, call

Ok so hello all, this has really been bugging me, how can I call like other code in a different file? (All I know is simple scripting where you can call a function, is it the same?) Because say I want my user to input "north" than have it do a action like `if (input.equals("north") { //blah` etc, this has been bugging me forever not knowing how to do this so thanks for any help.

**To clear and questions up**
Basically all I want is to be able to call other code in a different class.

Comment: Are both the classes related to java? I guess you want to know about inter process communication in java where one process of java communicated with the other

Comment: Yes I would love to learn that because I am using a gui and everything is in the buttonAction and that isn't working xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they are in the same package as a given class (by making sure they have the same `package packageName;` line at the top of the java source files), you can simply instantiate objects that belong those classes which are defined in different files as you would any other object:

```
ClassFromAnotherFile obj = new ClassFromAnotherFile();
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I understand a bit more, but what about something like a single variable? Same way or no?

Comment: A variable can't exist "by itself". It will either be a class (static) variable or an instance variable. If it's a static variable, you can just do `ClassFromAnotherFile.getVariable()`, if it's an instance variable you'd do `obj.getVariable()`.

Comment: Do accept the answer by clicking the check at the left of it, if it helped you!